# typedef void far *LPVOID ->Objective C

Tags: objective-c

```
typedef void far *LPVOID
LPVOID is the name and it's defined as a far pointer to void.
```

How to declare this dataype in Objective C.

`void far* my_pointer;` is giving me an error.

Comment: What language is the code you gave, and what error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`far` is a non-standard DOS/Windows anachronism, you just want:

```
typedef void * LPVOID;

LPVOID my_pointer;
```

Comment: Actually, I'd say you don't - typedefing pointers is Bad Style in my book.

Comment: @Neil: indeed, but I'assuming he's porting Windows code which is peppered with LPVOIDs and other such Microsoft nastiness.